# Sensor TSL2591 with Arduino Mega

Tags: i2c

I have three light sensors  TSL2591, of signal I2C, that I need to connect (together) to an Arduino Mega. However, I'm not very sure of how share the SDA and SCL pins of the three sensors and I don't know how to change their address for the Arduino to read and show the data of each sensor.

I have already read sensor's [datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/TSL25911_Datasheet_EN_v1.pdf) but there is not much information about this.

Comment: ` there is not much information` ... what information is there? ... also, please add a link to the data sheet to your question (do not put the link into comments)

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the datasheet, the TSL2591 does not *appear* to have a comfigurable address mechanism, therefore you are most likely obliged to use an I2C Multiplexer.

One example of such a device is the [TCA9545A](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tca9545a.pdf), *Low Voltage 4-channel I2C and SMbus Switch With Interrupt Logic and Reset Functions*, that can split one I2C line into 4 buses.

[image: TCA9545A pinout]

They are very easy to use and the pinout (and datasheet) are self explanatory.

Don't forget that you will need 3k3 Ω resistors on the `INT`, `RESET`, `SDA` and `SCL` lines from the Arduino *and* on **each** of the `INTx`, `SDx`, and `SCx` lines from the TCA9545A:

[image: TCA9545A Typical Application Schematic]

Comment: Adafruit has a module with the TCA9548A. The advantage is that these multiplexer chips will also do level shifting for sda and scl. That is needed because the arduino mega is a 5v board and the sensor is a 3.3v sensor. An arduino mega has 10k pullup resistors. Pullup resistors for all the sensors should still be added if they are not on the tsl2591 module.